# cucumber assertion not working with Async in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, assert

I'm writing a cucumber test, please find the code below. In this test, I'm trying to fail my test using `cucumber-assert` but my cucumber test is getting passed instead of failing the test.

**Steps.js**

```
const { Given, When, Then } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
const assert = require('cucumber-assert');
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

var result

Given('the client invoke valid request', async function () {
    result = await getData();
    assert.equal(result, 'true');
});


const getData = function () {
    var client = new Client();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var args = {
            parameters: {
                id: "3839KKD",
                name: 'test'
            },
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        };
        client.post("http://myhost", args, function (data, response, err) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else {
                resolve('false')
            }
        });

    })
}
```

**Cucumber log output**

```
.

1 scenario (1 passed)
1 step (1 passed)
0m00.613s (executing steps: 0m00.607s)
```

Why my cucumber test is not failing, what mistake I'm doing here - any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!